# Is there a way to find out if a driver is Uber eats or Uber taxi

Tags: uber-api

The Driver API does not seem to indicate what the driver is working as. I am under the impression that Uber require separate accounts for the same driver if they are doing both work streams.

Comment: fwiw, a friend drives for Uber Eats. The same app allows him to drive for regular Uber. He does not do that but it looks like the offer is there for him to use.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, from my experience the drivers seem to have separate accounts which I can understand as the insurance and driver ratings are unique to the work stream. I am looking at the insurance side that needs to be pushed to Uber and we get a lot of drivers mistakenly using their eats acc for taxi insurance

Comment: Seems that it may be the users choice to separate the accounts and @Rob is correct